# How do I remove pagination in wordpress for a single site?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I like to keep the standard settings for pagination, but on a single site remove the pagination. How can I do it?

I use the following site, pagination should be removed for this site: https://github.com/Alpenverein/DAV-Theme/blob/master/archive-personas.php

Or in other words: I need the while loop of that page to run through all entries, not stop when the amount for page 1 is reached:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom `WP_Query` and get all posts.

Also it's probably best to remove the call to the `pagination` function, if you don't want that for that archive view at all.

There's a `posts_per_page` query parameter that you have to set to `-1`. ([ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters))

For the case of this archive page, you also have to set the `post_type` parameter to `personas`. ([ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters))
Assuming that the post type is called `personas`. But you can derive that from the file name. Since the naming-scheme for custom post type archive templates is `archive-{post-type}.php`. ([ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/#custom-post-type-templates))

```php
$query = new WP_Query([
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'personas',
]);
```

Then instead of

```php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

you use

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

like shown in the docs. ([ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#standard-loop))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! The limit is gone now, unfortunately I get instead of the posts of the teammembers the posts of events that happened. So seems the query gets other results now, I would need to focus the query somehow to the personas.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the `post_type` parameter with more references to the docs